# SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

Greetins, I have some trouble with PDO functions.

**MY CODE:**

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'")) !== FALSE) {
        if($i > 0) {
            $data = str_replace('"', '', $data); 
            $myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('-','-',$data[0])));
            $data = str_replace(' ', '', $data);
            $lastname = $data[1];
            $firstname = $data[2];
            $showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '%$lastname%'");
            $showdata->execute();
            $rowas= $showdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $userioID = $rowas['userID'];

            $removals=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM late WHERE userID = '$userioID' AND dateandtime= '$myDate' ;");
            $removals->execute();


            $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);                      
            $import->bindParam(2, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $import->bindParam(3, $rowas['userID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->execute();
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Without **removals** part everything is working just fine. With removals - I get error: *SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (SQLExecute[-3030] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems that something is wrong with userID part in removal... Anyone can advise?

Comment: Are you dealing with string values that contain Unicode characters other than those with plain ASCII equivalents?

Comment: userID values are simple numbers.

Comment: Obviously something is wrong with userID syntax in removals, but cant find what exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a string to an integer. This cannot work.

```
userID = '$userioID'
```

If the "userID" is an int you cannot compare it to string like '1'.
Something like this may work:

```
userID = $userioID
```

I would also consider using bindParam method in all your SQL queries.